# can't set back original irc nick in hex chat

Tags: irc

I am using a hex chat. I am not able to fall back to my original irc nick.

example: original nick: `sourabh`,  last time I change it to `sourabh|away`. Now I am not able to set back to `sourabh`. I can set `sourabh_` etc. Can anyone help me with this. I am not good at `irc`.

I am not getting any error, that's confusing me.

Comment: The name is probably in use. Use `/ison sourabh` or `/whois sourabh`. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_commands

Comment: after running /whois sourabh *[sourabh] is away (I am away) *[sourabh] xx.xx.xx.xx :actually using host *[sourabh] idle 14:22:00, signon: Mon May 18 21:32:11 *[sourabh] End of WHOIS list.

Comment: There you go. The name is in use. Does the IP match your IP? Either someone has taken your name or a previous session is still open or not timed out.

Comment: @Appleoddity, correct that is another session that is still open. What would be the way to closed that?

Comment: Is it your IP or someone else’s? The session will close when you close the connection. There’s nothing to prevent someone else from using your name. I’m pretty sure it would’ve timed out by now.

Comment: @Appleoddity, it must be mine. Session is still on even I have restart my system.

Comment: “Must be mine” is not an answer. Your IP either matches the IP in the Whois command or it doesn’t. Go to google and type in ‘what’s my ip.’ If it doesn’t match, the answer is simple. Someone else took your name. That’s it.

Comment: @Appleoddity, I am using it through VPN so I said it must be mine.

Comment: You’re still capable of figuring out your public IP through a VPN. This is not complicated. Did you check what’s my IP and compare the two? I don’t know what else to tell you. The name is already in use. Pick a different one.